# Why is this taking so long - do I have a loop somewhere or something?

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I am pretty new to VBA and have created a spreadsheet where I can enter information on 'chases' and emails sent to various people. I want to have a button press that will organise and copy over the responses to an archive (the next worksheet) so I can know the history of a particular contact.

I have this code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For j = 3 To 50

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheets("Current").Rows(j).Copy
    Sheets("Archive").Rows(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'these two copy/paste into the archive

    Sheets("Archive").Range("A2:H2" & Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete 'this deletes blank rows

    Sheets("Archive").Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 6), Header:=xlYes 'this removes duplicates


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("Table2[[#All],[Next Chase]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current").ListObjects("Table2").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

End With


    Next j

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

If someone could help me with this and tidy it up a bit, or tell me where I'm going wrong I'd be much obliged. Thanks.

Edit: I think I need the delete blank rows function as There is a further piece of code that timestamps an entry into column F. When deleting information (chases) that are no longer needed I delete the rows A to F and this makes the timestamp (column G) and the 'next action' column H disappear using an Ifblank statement.

This is the code that timestamps into column F:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rChange As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rCell In rChange
        If rCell > "" Then
            With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                .Value = Now
                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            End With
        Else
            rCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
        End If
    Next
End If

ExitHandler:
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rChange = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

and the if statement in column H: '=IF(ISBLANK(G15)," ",WORKDAY(G15,2))'

Comment: You do have a loop. It will loop 47 times. I am going to guess that it is slow because it is deleting any blank lines 47 times. As nothing else seems to be massive. Do you need to delete blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I'd suggest to clean this up.

1) For ease of reference you should declare some Worksheet variables for the two sheets you use.

```
Dim C_S As Worksheet
Set C_S = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current")
Dim A_S as Worksheet
Set A_S = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archive")
```

2) Rather than using `For j = 3 To 50` it seems like you could more tightly control the loop by using this (would follow turning off screen updating)

```
Dim j as Long

j = 3

Do While C_S.Range("G" & j).Value <> ""
    'Copy the data
    C_S.Range("A" & j & ":H" & j).Copy

    'Paste it to the next open row in Archive
    A_S.Range("A" & A_S.Range("I1").Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Replace I1 with some cell where you can enter the following formula without worrying about it getting overwritten
        ' =COUNTA(G:G)+1  ALSO, if there are any blank rows above your data (ex. you leave row 1 blank and have the headers in row 2) you need to increase the "+1" by 1 for each blank

    'Increment j
    j = j + 1
Loop

'Your sort should go here now
```

Change 2 is especially helpful as you'll not repeat the sorting with each new row of data, you'll use true copy/paste as opposed to row insertion (which is slower), and by using the `COUNTA()`formula in a cell to determine the row to paste into you avoid having blank rows and can thus stop taking time to remove them.